# Matplotlib 3D Plot does not work as expected

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

as a Python and Stackoverflow Newbie, please excuse my dumb question. I've been working on this quite some time without making progress. I'm trying to set up a 3D Plot with X Y Z vectors for the respective axes.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib import cm
import numpy as np
import pandas, io
data = np.array([[0 ,0 ,1918],
                [1000 ,0 ,2001],
                [2000 ,0 ,2031],
                [3000 ,0 ,2048],
                [0 ,1000 ,2001],
                [1000 ,1000 ,2084],
                [2000 ,1000 ,2114],
                [3000 ,1000 ,2131],
                [0 ,2000 ,2031],
                [1000 ,2000 ,2114],
                [2000 ,2000 ,2144],
                [3000 ,2000 ,2161],
                [0 ,3000 ,2048],
                [1000 ,3000 ,2131],
                [2000 ,3000 ,2161],
                [3000 ,3000 ,2178]])
df = pandas.DataFrame(data,columns=["X","Y","Z"])
print(df)
x, y = np.meshgrid(df['X'],df['Y'])
plt.clf()
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
myplot = ax.plot_surface(X=x,Y=y,Z=df['Z'])
plt.show(myplot)
```

The sample data has 16 data points. I understand that I have to transform the X and Y vectors into a 4x4 grid which defines each Z value in the space. This is what I try to achieve with np.meshgrid. The result should be a uniform area that with a constant slope from (0,0) towards (3000,3000). However, this is not what I see:

[Resulting Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9qAc7.png)

I'd be grateful for everybody pushing me in the right direction.

Comment: Could you please tell me which version of matplotlib you are using?

Comment: I use version 2.0.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have misunderstood `meshgrid`. E.g.

```
p,q = np.meshgrid(["a","b"],["X","Y"])
print(p)
print (q)
# results in
[['a' 'b']
 ['a' 'b']]
[['X' 'X']
 ['Y' 'Y']]
```

A meshgrid of two arrays with length `n` and `m` will result in two arrays with shape `(m,n)`. If you put your complete coordinate list into meshgrid, it will result in a 16 by 16 matrix, not a 4 by 4 matrix as required.

Here you already have all the coordinates, they are just not in 2D shape. So the idea would be to simply reshape the coordinate lists, using `numpy.reshape`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np

data = np.array([[0 ,0 ,1918],
                [1000 ,0 ,2001],
                [2000 ,0 ,2031],
                [3000 ,0 ,2048],
                [0 ,1000 ,2001],
                [1000 ,1000 ,2084],
                [2000 ,1000 ,2114],
                [3000 ,1000 ,2131],
                [0 ,2000 ,2031],
                [1000 ,2000 ,2114],
                [2000 ,2000 ,2144],
                [3000 ,2000 ,2161],
                [0 ,3000 ,2048],
                [1000 ,3000 ,2131],
                [2000 ,3000 ,2161],
                [3000 ,3000 ,2178]])

x = data[:,0].reshape(4,4)
y = data[:,1].reshape(4,4)
z = data[:,2].reshape(4,4)
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
ax.plot_surface(X=x,Y=y,Z=z)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much! I'll take a deeper look into np.reshape.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks alright, although the use of pandas is redundant. It looks like that data you're using is simply not what you're after, i.e. constant slope.

Here is my code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib import cm
import numpy as np
import io

data = np.array([[0 ,0 ,1918],
                [1000 ,0 ,2001],
                [2000 ,0 ,2031],
                [3000 ,0 ,2048],
                [0 ,1000 ,2001],
                [1000 ,1000 ,2084],
                [2000 ,1000 ,2114],
                [3000 ,1000 ,2131],
                [0 ,2000 ,2031],
                [1000 ,2000 ,2114],
                [2000 ,2000 ,2144],
                [3000 ,2000 ,2161],
                [0 ,3000 ,2048],
                [1000 ,3000 ,2131],
                [2000 ,3000 ,2161],
                [3000 ,3000 ,2178]])

X, Y = np.meshgrid(data[:, 0], data[:, 1])

Z = X + Y

plt.clf()
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
myplot = ax.plot_surface(X,Y,Z)
plt.show(myplot)
```

Which produces a surface of a plane.

Note that there is a a major difference: In your case, the Z is a 1D vector, whereas I have used `X + Y` which is a matrix.

The data you are using is basically a point cloud, so if you want to generate a surface from it you'll have to be a lot more specific about how to generate it.